# How to order documents by average aggregate of the nested childrens' property in RavenDB?

Tags: c#, ravendb, aggregate

Given a model like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Coordinates Geo { get; set; }

    public IList<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

How can I write a query that will return matching locations sorted in descending order by their Rating?

I have an index that allows me to query for locations within a certain radius around a geopoint:

```
public class Locations_ByCoordinates : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location>
{
    public Locations_ByCoordinates()
    {
        Map = locations => from l in locations
                           select new {_ = SpatialIndex.Generate(l.Geo.Lat, l.Geo.Lon)};
    }
}
```

This seems to work and I am able to sort the results like so:

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var query = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Location>(Names.Indexes.LocationsByCoordinates)
                       .Statistics(out stats)
                       .WithinRadiusOf(radius, coordinates.Lat, coordinates.Lon);

switch (sort)
{
    case Sort.Distance:
        query = query.SortByDistance();
        break;
    case Sort.Rating:
        query = query.AddOrder(l => l.Reviews.Average(r => r.Rating), true); // TODO: This throws an exception, perhaps a modified index with an aggregate is required? Maybe Map/Reduce?
        break;
    case Sort.Alphabetical:
        query = query.OrderBy(l => l.Name);
        break;
    case Sort.Number_of_ratings:
        query = query.AddOrder(l => l.Reviews.Count, true);
        break;
    case Sort.Relevance: // This is the default ordering in RavenDB.
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sort");
}
```

Every option works OK except sorting by average rating which throws an exception about unknown field. I feel this has to be a Map/Reduce index rather than a Map index. But I have no idea how to write it.

I am migrating this code from MongoDB, but I used to sort the documents by rating on the client side there, I thought I'd do this on the server side now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all reviews are in the location, and you want the average rating of the reviews for each location, you don't need to reduce.  Just create a new field in your map.

```
Map = locations => from l in locations
                   select new {
                       _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(l.Geo.Lat, l.Geo.Lon),
                       AvgRating = l.Reviews.Average(r => r.Rating)
                   };
```

Comment: That's what I don't get :), I keep thinking that the Map returns something. How do I use that AvgRating field to sort the results? Do I need to add an AvgRating property to my Location class or what?

Comment: Map just controls what get's indexed, i.e. the fields you can search on and order by. By default RavenDB will always return the complete docs that match the query.

Comment: I know that much in theory, but don't know how to apply that in practice. :) I changed the ordering by Rating in my `switch` block to this:
`query = query.AddOrder("AvgRating", true);`

It doesn't throw an error right now, but it also ruled out locations that don't have any reviews. I would still like to see them with Rating of 0.

Changed to:
`AvgRating = l.Reviews.Count > 0 ? l.Reviews.Average(r => r.Rating) : 0`

It now works great. But I still feel like doing magic, not fully understanding what is going on and that's bad. :(

Comment: Let's guess... When that index is initialized, RavenDB will add an AvgRating field to every document of type Location stored in Lucene. The value of that field gets calculated each time a Location is indexed. It is not storing `l.Reviews.Count > 0 ? l.Reviews.Average(r => r.Rating) : 0` translated to some Lucene query syntax, but the result of that chunk of C# code for each Location. So when a location gets re-indexed that C# code is ran and AvgRating field in the document stored in Lucene is updated with the new value (e.g., 3, 5, 1.5, etc.). Did I get it right or am I in the dark?

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak  You got it right. It's just like a "computed column" in SQL. You can see the value in Raven Studio if you click "index entries" from the query options when executing the index.